# Data isnt populating in ag-grid using angular 7

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to populate the ag-grid in angular with json data and for some reasons the data isn't binding. 
I am using ag-grid community edition and angular 7. I have ensured the references to the ag-grid is correct.
I have created stackblitz example to reproduce the issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pz3gau

Component

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import "ag-grid-community";
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;

  private columnDefs;
  private components;
  private rowData: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Athlete",
        field: "athlete"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Date",
        field: "date",
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: "datePicker"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Age",
        field: "age"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Country",
        field: "country"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Year",
        field: "year"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Sport",
        field: "sport"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Gold",
        field: "gold"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Silver",
        field: "silver"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Bronze",
        field: "bronze"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Total",
        field: "total"
      }
    ];

  }

   onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http
      .get(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json"
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.rowData = data;
      });
  }
}
```

html

```
 <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [components]="components"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to change

1. In `app.component.html`, change style to `style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"`

Having 100% as width/height doesn't work here as parent container doesn't have  height/width.

2. You forgot to import css files of `ag-grid`.

add these 2 files in `style.css`

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

Now you should see your data on the screen!

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion but does not work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzjwxt. Its better if you could edit my stackblitz and show me

Comment: Here you go, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9xcdwy
You still didn't add the styles.